# How to create scm for function apps azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, teams-toolkit

I have function app in my azure for MS Teams app development. When I try to deploy Teams app with dev environment (vsc -> Teams Toolkit -> Lifecycle -> Deploy) everythings working fine except last step (Deploy: [8/8]) and there is:

```
Summary:
(×) Error: Lifecycle stage deploy failed.
  (√) Done: cli/runNpmCommand(install dependencies) was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Successful execution of the `npm install` command at `c:\<app_directory>\<app-name>\client\`.
  (√) Done: cli/runNpmCommand(build app) was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Successful execution of the `npm run build --if-present` command at `c:\<app_directory>\<app-name>\client\`.
  (√) Done: azureStorage/deploy was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Successfully deployed `c:\<app_directory>\<app-name>\client\build` to Azure Storage.
  (√) Done: cli/runNpmCommand(install dependencies) was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Successful execution of the `npm install` command at `c:\<app_directory>\<app-name>\client\api`.
  (√) Done: cli/runNpmCommand(build app) was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Successful execution of the `npm run build --if-present` command at `c:\<app_directory>\<app-name>\client\api`.
  (√) Done: devTool/install was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: .NET Core SDK is installed at C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe.
  (√) Done: cli/runDotnetCommand was executed successfully.
    (√) Done: Successful execution of the `dotnet build extensions.csproj -o bin --ignore-failed-sources` command at `c:\<app_directory>\<app-name>\client\api`.
  (×) Error: azureFunctions/zipDeploy failed.
    (×) Error: Unable to deploy zip package to endpoint 'https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true' in Azure due to error: {"stack":"Error: remote server error with status code: 500, message: \"<!DOCTYPE html>\\r\\n<html>\\r\\n    <head>\\r\\n        <title>The network path was not found.<br></title>\\r\\n  ...
```

I've checked address `https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net` and doesn't exist exactly. Is there any possibility to add this scm?

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved my problem: just deleted function app and create new with selecting storage. Now there is `https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`, but I think I should setting teams `.env.dev` one more time.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is

```
remote server error with status code: 500, message: The network path was not found.
```

It seems your Azure Function resources don't exist. Please check the location of your Azure Function in the `.env.dev` file and make sure it can be found in your Azure portal.